# Convert string to array of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a string of the following form:

```
"[{'status': 'Unshipped', 'city': 'New Delhi', 'buyer_name': 'xxx', 'name': 'xxx', 'countryCode': 'IN', 'payment_method': 'COD', 'y_id': 'xxx', 'phone': 'xxx', 'state': 'New Delhi', 'service': 'Expedited', 'amout': '425.00', 'address_1': 'xxx', 'address_2': 'xxx', 'postalCode': '110018', 'shipped_by_y': 'false', 'channel': 'MFN', 'order_type': 'StandardOrder'}, {'status': 'Unshipped', 'city': 'thane', 'buyer_name': 'xxx', 'name': 'xxx', 'countryCode': 'IN', 'payment_method': 'COD', 'y_id': 'xxx', 'phone': 'xxx', 'state': 'Maharashtra', 'service': 'Expedited', 'amout': '350.00', 'address_1': 'xxx', 'address_2': 'xxx', 'postalCode': '400607', 'shipped_by_y': 'false', 'channel': 'MFN', 'order_type': 'StandardOrder'}]\n"
```

How can I convert this string to an array of corresponding dictionaries.

I tried to convert the string to JSON and then loading the JSON. But it remains a string.

Comment: And how did you convert it to JSON then, for it to remain a string when you loaded it? Can you show us a *real* example rather one made up? Are there no quotes around the keys and values, for example?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I did a json.dumps followed by json.loads

Comment: If the string is valid JSON, try to only use `loads`.

Comment: @nish: This isn't valid JSON. This looks like a Python string instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But I am doing a json.dumps before json.loads. Would thatnot work?

Comment: @nish: Then show us that code. You didn't here; JSON uses *double* quotes. Perhaps you dumped output of `str()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have JSON there; that looks like you converted a Python list with dictionaries to string directly.

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert it back to Python objects:

```
import ast

obj = ast.literal_eval(datastring)
```

`ast.literal_eval()` limits parsing to just object literals (tuples, lists, dictionaries, strings, numbers), avoiding the arbitrary code execution risks that a full-blown `eval()` call carries with it.

Demo:

```
>>> import ast
>>> datastring = "[{'status': 'Unshipped', 'city': 'New Delhi', 'buyer_name': 'xxx', 'name': 'xxx', 'countryCode': 'IN', 'payment_method': 'COD', 'y_id': 'xxx', 'phone': 'xxx', 'state': 'New Delhi', 'service': 'Expedited', 'amout': '425.00', 'address_1': 'xxx', 'address_2': 'xxx', 'postalCode': '110018', 'shipped_by_y': 'false', 'channel': 'MFN', 'order_type': 'StandardOrder'}, {'status': 'Unshipped', 'city': 'thane', 'buyer_name': 'xxx', 'name': 'xxx', 'countryCode': 'IN', 'payment_method': 'COD', 'y_id': 'xxx', 'phone': 'xxx', 'state': 'Maharashtra', 'service': 'Expedited', 'amout': '350.00', 'address_1': 'xxx', 'address_2': 'xxx', 'postalCode': '400607', 'shipped_by_y': 'false', 'channel': 'MFN', 'order_type': 'StandardOrder'}]\n"
>>> ast.literal_eval(datastring)
[{'status': 'Unshipped', 'city': 'New Delhi', 'buyer_name': 'xxx', 'name': 'xxx', 'countryCode': 'IN', 'payment_method': 'COD', 'shipped_by_y': 'false', 'phone': 'xxx', 'state': 'New Delhi', 'service': 'Expedited', 'address_1': 'xxx', 'address_2': 'xxx', 'postalCode': '110018', 'order_type': 'StandardOrder', 'amout': '425.00', 'channel': 'MFN', 'y_id': 'xxx'}, {'status': 'Unshipped', 'city': 'thane', 'buyer_name': 'xxx', 'name': 'xxx', 'countryCode': 'IN', 'payment_method': 'COD', 'shipped_by_y': 'false', 'phone': 'xxx', 'state': 'Maharashtra', 'service': 'Expedited', 'address_1': 'xxx', 'address_2': 'xxx', 'postalCode': '400607', 'order_type': 'StandardOrder', 'amout': '350.00', 'channel': 'MFN', 'y_id': 'xxx'}]
```